# wpf two way binding not working

Tags: wpf, vb.net, binding, inotifypropertychanged, two-way

i have

```
 <Grid Name="thisPage">
  <TextBlock Name="tbtb" />
  <ScrollViewer Name="sv4" Visibility="Hidden">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                 <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                       <TextBox Text="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/> 
                     </DataTemplate> 
                 </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate> 
             </ItemsControl>
   </ScrollViewer>
  </Grid>
```

in the MainWindow.vb, i have

```
movieArray as ObservableCollection(of Movie)

For i As Integer = 0 To 5 
        Me.movieArray.Add(New Movie(i)) 
    Next

Me.sv4.DataContext = Me.movieArray
Me.listBox5.DataContext = Me.movieArray
```

---

```
 Private Sub TextBox_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs)

        Me.tbtb.Text = ""
        For Each m As Movie In movieArray
            Me.tbtb.Text += p.Title.ToString + " ^ "
        Next
       End Sub
```

---

```
Class Movie
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

  Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler _
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal info As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(info))
    End Sub

 Property Title As Integer
        Get
            Return Me._title
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            Me._title = value
            If Not (value = _title) Then
                Me._title= value
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Title")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
```

---

for the next page i have,

```
 <Grid Name="nextPage" Visibility="Hidden" > 
            <ListBox Name="listBox5" >
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                    </DataTemplate> 
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate> 
            </ItemsControl>
        </ListBox>
        </Grid >
```

To change pages i just toggle the visibility of thisPage and nextPage using back, next buttons.

IM not sure what im doing wrong as:-

1. listbox5 shows only the original values, not anything changed by
   textboxes.
2. tbtb, however is able to update its values

Comment: got it.

it was the extra  `Me._title = value` in the set method before the if condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem might be your 'Title' property setter.

I'm a C# guy, not a VB expert... but it would appear that NotifyPropertyChanged will never get called.

`value = _title` will always be true because you just set `Me._title = value` in the previous line of code. Thus you will never execute any of the code in your if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using Textchanged evetn in two way binding you dont need kind of stuff. two way binding is directly bind values from your view to property and from property to view

so don't use textchanged event and try again. this will work.

Comment: its to verify if things were working initially, if it works in textchanged it should work on the next paage. Also, i tried without textchanged, it wasn't working